# How to do multicast of push notification?

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am able to send notification one device at a time.
I need to change php code or java code?
Below is my code:

Create a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe Java code on the Android app has nothing to do with sending multicast messages. You have to change the PHP code on your server.

If you want to send the same message to multiple devices you should send an HTTP request with `application/json` content type of the form :

```
{
  "registration_ids" : ["reg-id1","reg-id2",...],
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

This allows you to send the same message to up to 1000 devices in a single HTTP request.

Comment: indeed, you have to push notifications to all the users from the server side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252771/android-push-notification-gcm     This also worked for me.