# copy text to textarea and submit all form in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i have 20 user in my database and have 20 form in my site . this code show 20 form and i should send message every day to 20 user and want copy too all text area and submit them . i want have a form for send too all .

```
               <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <form id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" name="" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $row["id"] ?>')">
                            <label>Name: </label> <span><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <label>Email:</label> <span><?php echo $row["email"] ?></span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="send_container">                                
                                <textarea rows="3" name="message" cols="25" class="txt_message" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
                                <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/>
                                <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send" onclick=""/>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                    </li>
                <?php }
            } else { ?> 
                <li>
                    No Users Registered Yet!
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
```

tihs code create 20 form with 20 id and :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        });
        function sendPushNotification(id){
            var data = $('form#'+id).serialize();
            $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');                
            $.ajax({
                url: "send_message.php",
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                      $('.txt_message').val("");
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Ok just i want 1 form too send too all , no more.

Comment: You'll need to put your form tags and submit buttons outside the while, and change your textbox name to an array, like `name="message[]"`. This way, in your *send_message.php* you'll just need to use *for* to get the values from the post array.

Comment: To me it is not clear what you are asking. Could you please try to describe what you want to achieve and where you got stuck?

Comment: i create http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/  and with this post  http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/16252771/android-push-notification-gcm   change to send too all form  . this work fine for 50 user but my user are 500 and not send with this way .

Comment: dimas this way not work for 500 user